# Lazy evaluate Pandas dataframe filters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm observing a behavior that's weird to me, can anyone tell me how I can define filter once and re-use throughout my code?

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], columns=['A'])
>>> my_filter = df.A == 2
>>> df.loc[1] = 5
>>> df[my_filter]
   A
1  5
```

I expect my_filter to return empty dataset since none of the A columns are equal to 2.

I'm thinking about making a function that returns the filter and re-use that but is there any more pythonic as well as pandaic way of doing this?

```py
def get_my_filter(df):
    return df.A == 2

df[get_my_filter()]
change df
df[get_my_filter()]
```

Comment: What's wrong with doing `df[df.A == 2]` again after modifying the dataframe?

Comment: @fsimonjetz nothing, but imagine you have a very complex filter of 10 lines and many clauses, you don't want to keep re-writing it. so I was trying to find out the panda-ic way of re-using filters.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess your idea is what I'd do, too – it seems like a relatively rare case to have the exact same, complex filter twice, but I might be wrong.

Comment: yeah maybe if you need it twice, rather make a top level function out of it.. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

you applied the filter in the first place. Changing a value in the row won't help.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], columns=['A'])
my_filter = df.A == 2
print(my_filter)
'''
    A
0   False
1   True
2   False

'''
```

as you can see, it returns a series. If you change the data after this process, it will not work. because this represents the first version of the df. But you can use define filter as a string. You can achieve what you want if you use the string filter inside the **eval()** function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], columns=['A'])
my_filter = 'df.A == 2'
df.loc[1] = 5
df[eval(my_filter)]

'''
Out[205]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A]
Index: []
'''
```

Comment: Using `eval` can be dangerous because it can and will execute whatever it is passed. If you *really* want to do something like that, there is `df.query` which allows you to do `df.query("A == 2")`. But I don't see the point to be honest, might as well just do `df[df.A==2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Masks are not dynamic, they stay how you defined them when you defined them.
So if you still need to change the dataframe value, you should swap lines 2 and 3.
That would work.